# Re: Publishing your Iphone app to Cydia?

Tags: ios, crash, jailbreak, cydia, deb

**My Iphone Game crashes on Launch**

I have created my application on Xcode and then I made my `DEBIAN` directory and my `control` file inside of that directory it then successfully made my `.deb` file because I used the following command in the console `dpkg -b "(my apps name)"`. now once I have the `.deb` file I uploaded it to my Repo. The app then successfully installs from the Repo however once installed no matter how many times I `respring` or `Re-boot` my device the app crashes on launch.

Does anyone have any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: Idea: post the crash log. Blind guess: you haven't fake codesigned the binary.

Comment: I did use the fake code sign method to build the app for my device

Comment: And there was no crash log behind the reason for crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you package up your application into a deb you need to codesign the binary with ldid

**Make sure you sign the binary**

For example

```
ldid -S myappfolder/myapp
```

Also make sure the correct permissions are set.

```
 chmod 0755 myappfolder/myapp
 chown 0:0 myappfolder/myapp
```

Comment: Okay thanks alot for the reply I will try the code later

Comment: @TheCODER999, you shouldn't accept answers if you don't know if they work.  This answer is *fake code signing*.  You said in your comment above that you used the *fake code sign method*.  It's very hard to help you if you don't give accurate answers to the questions people ask you in their comments.

Comment: I have used you're code and I'm gatting a error Here it is:util/ldid.cpp(567): _assert(0:arch != NULL) and yes i am running on armv7. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are probably using an older ldid binary that does not support newer architectures. Download this one and run it from your mac terminal. "https://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/list" Or set your arch to "armv6" in your project configuration also make sure to set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "YES"